# Select Extensions that the user is not subscribed to already

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've been searching for a solution for my problem on Stack Overflow but I can't seem to find a solution that fits, or that I'm able to implement.

I have three tables: "Extensions", "Subscriptions", "Accounts".

Extensions table:

| extension_id | extension_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | First Ext |
| 2 | Second Ext |

Subscriptions table:

| subscription_id | extension | user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

Accounts table:

| id | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Sara |

Here there are two extensions with ID one and two, and user with ID one is subscribed to both in the subscriptions table.

I have been successful in getting a list of the extensions the signed in user is subscribed to by doing:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    codium.extensions 
JOIN 
    codium.subscriptions 
JOIN 
    codium.accounts
WHERE 
    extensions.extension_id = subscriptions.extension 
AND 
    accounts.id = subscriptions.user 
AND 
    accounts.id = :id
```

Then in php define what :id is with `$sql->execute(["id" => $_SESSION["user_id"]]);`.

However, I have been unsuccessful in showing a list of subscriptions the user is **not** subscribed to. If the user is subscribed to just the first extension, show the second. If the user is subscribed to none at all, show both extensions.

If it matters, when the query is executed, I use `$extensions = $sql->fetchAll();`, then foreach to echo a list.

I've been at this problem for a long time, using Google and logic as my friend, but I can't seem to make it work. Either none shows, or I get the correct result in very specific circumstances, i.e. if the user is just subscribed to one extension.

Appreciate all possible help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing old and new styles of `JOIN, when you keep to the newer one nothing can go almost wrong.

besides test yor queries before using them in code, if you are not firm with the syntax

```
SELECT 
    ex.*, su.*,ac.*
FROM 
    codium.extensions ex
JOIN 
    codium.subscriptions su ON ex.extension_id = su.extension  
JOIN 
    codium.accounts ac ON ac.id = su.user 
WHERE         
    ac.id = :id
```

For your problem.

This shows all ROWS from extensions which are not in subscriber and conected to the selected user

```
SELECT * FROM
Extensions e1
WHERE
   extension_id NOT IN (SELECT extension FROM Subscriptions  WHERE user = :id)
```

For marking the extension already present you can use LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT ei.*, IF(su.subscription_id IS NOT NULL, 1,0) as marked FROM
Extensions e1 LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT subscription_id ,extension FROM Subscriptions  WHERE user = :id) su ON ex.extension_id = su.extension
```

Comment: I am sorry if I wasn't clear but showing a list of already subscribed extensions already works, my problem is showing every extension except the extensions the user is already subscribed to

Your answer was still helpful though, so I can get better at writing queries, although mixing old and new join style worked.

Comment: which database are you using , please tag it corrrectly, i will add a solution when i know which databse you are using

Comment: I am using mysql i guess if thats a type. phpmyadmin as interface

Comment: ok check the added query

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It worked! 
A side question if you dont mind. Using the first sql you added, is it possible to in a list of all extensions, mark the one already subscribed?
When using foreach to list them all, to have the ones where the user is subscribed say "Subscribed"?

Comment: see my last edit, you can do this in sql and when marked is 1 , thie sbscription alredy exists, so you need only run once to make your html cpde

Comment: Do you use that last one standalone or combined with other sql? I get Unknown column 'su.subscription_id' in 'field list' when using standalone. Turns into Unknown column 'ex.extension_id' in 'on clause' when I type SELECT * FROM subscriptions instead of just SELECT extension

Comment: yeahh the subsekect has to include all used columns, i changed it to work, still you need to learn how sql work, if you want to continue